# Electron + React, dmg app is crashing in MAC, how to debug a dmg build?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge

I am working on an electron project which is crashing on launch only on my mac (M2 chip). Also happening in users machine. Getting the below error, something related to memory issue

```
Exception Type: EXC BAD ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN INVALID ADDRESS at 0x7f34deffeffeffff -> 0x00005effeffeffff (possible pointer authentication failure)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x7f34deffeffeffff
Exception Note:
Termination Reason: EXC CORPSE NOTIFY

VM Region Info: Ox5effeffeffff is not in any region. Bytes after previous region: 23333468823552 Bytes before following region:
35712921567233
REGION TYPE
JS JIT generated code
---> GAP OF 0x35b3cf1fe000 BYTES
MALLOC MEDIUM
START - END
[ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD REGION DETAIL
49c73001000-49c73002000 [
4K1
---/rwX SM=NUL
7f700000000-77b00800000 [ 8192K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV
Thread 0 Crashed:: CrBrowserMain Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

I have tried different ways to check the root cause for the crash.

- Tried to add sentry, that didn't give much insight.
- Added logs to find where exactly failure happening, but not getting the logs for crash
- Tried adding events like `uncaughtException` to capture the crash

Seems the crash is mostly due build related issue and not JS related.

How to debug the build or how to debug system level app crash?
Or anyone face similar issue before and solved?

Your inputs would be a great help! Thanks in advice.